# Optimizing Spark resources to avoid memory and space usage

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have a dataset that is around 190GB that was partitioned into 1000 partitions.

my EMR cluster allows a maximum of 10 `r5a.2xlarge` TASK nodes and 2 CORE nodes. Each node having 64GB mem and 128GB EBS storage.

In my spark job execution, I have set it to use `executor-cores 5`, `driver cores 5`,`executor-memory 40g`, `driver-memory 50g`, `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=10g`, `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=500`, `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true`

But my job keeps failing with errors like

```
spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException
spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException
java.io.IOException: No space left on device
Container Lost
etc...
```

A lot of the answers to these kinds of issues that I found online say to increase the memoryOverhead. Which i did, from 2G to 10G. My total `executor memory` and `memoryOverhead` is 50G. with 40G allocated to executor and 10G allocated to overhead. But I think I am reaching the limit since I won't be able to go above 56.

I thought i did all that was possible to optmize my spark job:

1. Increase partitions
2. Increase spark.sql.shuffle.partitions
3. Increase executor and overhead memory

But my job still fails. Is there anything else I can try? Should i increase my overhead even more so that my executor memory/overhead memory is 50/50?
The memory profile of my job from ganglia looks something like this:

(The steep drop is when the cluster flushed all the executor nodes due to them being dead)

[image]

Any insight would be greatly appreciated

Thank You

**EDIT:[SOLUTION]**

I am appending to my post with the exact solution that solved my problem thanks to `Debuggerrr` based on his suggestions in his answer.

- I had a large data frame that I was re-using after doing many
  computations on other dataframes. By using the `persist()` method
  (suggested by Debuggerrr), I was able to save that to MEMORY and DISC
  and simply call it back without parts of it being cleaned up by the
  GC.
- I also followed the best practices blog Debuggerrr mentioned in his answer and calculated the correct executor memory, number of executors etc. But what I failed to do was disable `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled`. The blog states that it is best to set the property to false if we are calculating the resources manually since spark tends to misallocate resources if your calculation doesnt line up with it. Once I set it to false, and set the correct executor and spark attributes, it worked like a charm!

**[EDIT 2]:**
The parameters *that specifically worked for my job* are:

```
--executor-cores 5 --driver-cores 5 --executor-memory 44g --driver-memory 44g --num-executors 9 --conf spark.default.parallelism=100 --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=300 --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=11g --conf spark.shuffle.io.retryWait=180s --conf spark.network.timeout=800s --conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try either of the below steps:

1. `Memory overhead` should be `10%` of the Executor memory or `328 MB`. Don't increase it to any value.
2. Remove Driver Cores.
3. If you have 10 nodes, then specify the `number of executors`. You have to calculate it in such a way that you leave some space for YARN and background processes. Also, you can try increasing 1 or 2 more cores.
4. Run it on a `cluster` mode and whatever number you assign to executors, add +1 to it since 1 executor will be treated as driver executor in the cluster mode.
5. Also, the last thing is nothing but your code written to submit / process that 190GB of file. Go through your code and find ways of optimizing it. Look for collect methods, or unnecessary use of joins, coalesce / repartition. Find some alternatives to it if it isn't needed.
6. Use persist(Memory and Disk only) option for the data frames that you are using frequently in the code.
7. Also the last thing which I tried is to execute the steps manually on the `spark-shell on EMR` and you will come to know which part of the code is taking much time to run.

You can also refer to this [official blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/best-practices-for-successfully-managing-memory-for-apache-spark-applications-on-amazon-emr/) for some of the tips.

Comment: Thank you for those insights!. 
I am using `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true`, so I am not specifying the number of executors since it would be taken care of by the yarn. I have seen the number of executors go upto 11.
I am running it only on cluster mode and I dont have any collect method in my code. So i guess I am already doing points 3,4 and 5 as you mentioned.
I am using a dataframe frequently, I can try the persist option.

Comment: (Continuing comment from above)
For point no.7, I tested my code on a very small subset in jupiterlab notebook, and it works fine. However I think my dataset is highly skewed. Is there a way to check for the skewness?

Comment: The point about mentioning the `num-executors` parameter is that even if you leave on Spark to take care of executors, you can observe that it goes up to a max of 11 executors even though you have assigned `40GB` of ram per executor and you have 10 nodes with you. The point is the memory is not fully utilized and also affects parallelism. More executors the more parallelism. Assume 40GB of ram is assigned to 1 executor, Max 5GB(which is not occupied usually) for YARN overhead and other background processes. Still you left with 19GB RAM per node.

Comment: Calculate it in such a way that you assign at least 2 executors per node and distribute the memory accordingly. Try increasing CPU cores too.

Comment: The other point about using `collect` is that I just wanted to highlight `any part of your code` that brings load on your driver thread. In that case either you find the alternative to it (if there is any) or increase the driver memory.

Comment: Don't try it on Jupyter notebook. Invoke the `spark-shell` with the spark-submit parameters and test it on EMR. Regarding data skewness, you have to study data. For example separate data with null values from non-null values. Later on, just left join on non-null data and some union. This is the scenario that I faced in my earlier days. Your case might be different. This avoids shuffling.

Comment: I tried your suggestions and it worked. I have appended my question to include what exactly worked for me based on your suggestions. Thank You!
Regarding your point about assigning at least 2 executors per node, I have 10 nodes which means I should assign a total of 20 executors. But the blog you suggested mentions ((total cores -1)/number of CPU cores) * number of nodes)-1
I have 8 available cores per node and have assigned 5 executor cores which gives me
(((8-1)/5) * 10)-1 = 9 (rounded down)
Could I have used 20 instead?

Comment: You can try with 15, if you are not comfortable with 20. The point is if you have 9 executors with 10 nodes and 40GB ram, assuming 1 executor will be on 1 node then still u have 1 node which is idle (memory is underutilized). If you assign 15 then each node will have atleast 1 executor and also parallelism is increased which leads to faster processing too. I am glad to know that it worked for you 

Comment: Also, I would like to suggest you to edit your question with the parameters that exactly worked for your problem.

Comment: Yes, based on the blog you suggested, it says to leave 1 executor for the driver. But I guess I can try with 15 next time :) 
Also, i have updated my question with the parameters that worked for me. Thanks again!

Comment: Great! And yes, as I said in my answer, in cluster mode, 1 executor is treated as driver thread that's why I asked you to +1 number of executors.